# NASM division is giving me the wrong results

Tags: linux, nasm, division

Alright, so I'm supposed to create a program that determines the day of any given date on NASM, I'm pretty sure I know what to do. However this is the first time I use NASM, and I'm clueless about some stuff. For instance I believe my issue with this division is related to the memory I'm allocating, if I change it to something else it always gives me a floating point error. Also I'm not quite sure I'm understanding division very well.

Here's my code:

```
;Dates and leap years 

%include "/home/usr/Desktop/io.mac"



.DATA 
day_msg db 'Enter the day(number from 1-31): ',0        ;prompt messages for the user, asks for day, month and year
month_msg db 'Enter the month(number from 1-12): ',0
year_msg db 'Enter the year: ',0
result_msg db 'The result is:',0
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------
.UDATA
day resb 1          ;memory reservations for day, month, year and the result of the operation
month resb 1        ;the output of the user is stored in these spaces, also kept around if they are required after the operation
year resd 1
result resb 1
temp resb 1
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.CODE 
    .STARTUP 
    ;asks user for day
    PutStr day_msg
    GetInt [day]

    ;asks user for month
    PutStr month_msg
    GetInt [month]  

    ;asks user for year
    PutStr year_msg
    GetInt [year]

    ;this performs the mathematical operation to figure out the day
    mov AX,[year]       ;saves AX with the year value 
    mov CX, 4       ;sets CX to 4
    div CX          ;divides AX by CX, which is 4
    mov [temp],AL   ;extracts result from division by 4 

    PutStr result_msg
    PutInt [temp]
    nwln 
    .EXIT
```

It's not doing everything yet, because I'm stuck in one of the divisions. For instance if I specify that the year is 1969, it throws 236 as an answer, that will give me an erroneous reading in the next steps. It should give me 492 instead. I don't understand why I'm getting that answer.

Comment: Since AL is one byte, you're never going to get 492 from there.

Comment: Did you forget to set `DX` to 0 before division? `DIV CX` means: "DX:AX/CX = AX remainder DX".

Comment: I see. I will change that then, I'm going about this wrong then. Its storing that value because it can't fit the 492. Thank you. I did forge that yes, but I know nothing about his. No one really explained division properly.